# Posting without a submit button

Tags: html, web

I was looking at a few websites that seems to update immediately after I select a certain condition from a dropdown list. It seems like Submit buttons are becoming a thing of the past. How is this being done?

An example site is: http://www.5stardealer.com/search

Comment: you need to readup on javascript/jquery

Comment: @Gerve thisis an example here http://www.5stardealer.com/search

Comment: @karthikr So is it Jquery? Care to actually expand on that?

Comment: basically, you create a jquery listener, which you are triggering a form submit or an ajax submit when something changes in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example page at http://www.5stardealer.com/search, the select (dropdown box) has an `onchange` event handler, so when changed it will submit the form.

The actual code is:

```
<select name="Model" style="margin-left:10px;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

As @pjmorse says, there are a lot of ways this can be done, this is just one.

Comment: Hi Gerve, thanks for that. I also asked pjmorse; how is it that a dropdown list of a particular inventory knows the quantity of each option?

Comment: I think this is done server side (probably with php), rather than with javascript. When the form is submitted, the server will work it all out.

Answer (score 2):

There are a *lot* of ways to do this. The `select` menu might have an `onchange` attribute which triggers a JS function to submit the form, for example.

Comment: Oh very cool! I think that's the answer I was looking for. Can I ask you - how is it that a dropdown list of a particular inventory knows the quantity of each option?

Comment: Again, there's more than one way to do it. It could be that the server is building the drop-down dynamically for each request, and drawing those quantities from its own copy of the inventory. It could also be updating the values dynamically from a web service using AJAX (a Javascript HTTP request in the background).

Answer (score 0):

They use Javascript. JQuery is a Javascript Library. They are using onclick/onchange/onfocus/etc to call Javascript functions when you do certain actions. Read up on JQuery at learn.jquery.com, they have some beginner tutorials there for JQuery and Javascript.

Note: JQuery is NOT required. But the site I linked has an excellent Javascript 101 article that will help teach you basic Javascript syntax. Once you know the basics of Javascript, learning a library like JQuery can be very useful.

Comment: There is no need to bring jQuery into this. You imply that jQuery is required; it is not.